# Storybook: Action with Return Value

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a React component that uses a `user`, which has a number of functions that should return a value. I am trying to write a story for this component using Storybook.

I want to achieve the following using the essential Storybook add-on `actions`:

```js
<Component user={{save: action('user-save'), hasLink: () => {return true;} }} />
```

I have found [this](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11290) GitHub issue, but I don't think they implemented the intended changes.